# Create, update and destroy actions in an UsersController that uses Devise for registration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, devise, registration

Should I implement the `new`, `create`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy` actions on a controller whose corresponding model uses Devise's `:registerable` module?

In other words, should I keep the CRUD interface even though Devise manages the registration process for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to manage your `User`s (or whatever your Devise model is called) via a CRUD interface, you'll need to have those actions available. Unless I'm mistaken, if you manage your `User`s with a CRUD setup, you'll need to remove the `:registerable` from the model.

If you want need/want a CRUD interface for your `User`s, you can remove the CRUD actions (Devise will work fine without a CRUD interface, or CRUD actions in your controller).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is it possible to have both setups at once?

Comment: If my memory is correct, you'll experience issues if you leave `:registrable` while providing your own CRUD interface. I can't recall what th issue was, though... More on creating a CRUD interface for Devise here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface